# NIST statistical tests

Tags: encryption, symmetric, nist, statistical-test, indistinguishability

I'm having trouble testing a not-so-popular algorithm that I haven't found an implementation of, so I wrote it myself and now I'd like to test it with nist tests, but I have a suspicion that I'm doing something wrong.

I got encrypted file with `~10,000,000` bits. I tested my algorithm in the following wayю.
I set the input parameter to `1,000,000`, it will look like: `/assess 1000000`, then the amount of bitstreams i put 10: `How many bitstreams? 10`. Then i chose to test my file as binary, since every symbol in my file is a char, which contains 8 bits:

```
    [0] ASCII - A sequence of ASCII 0's and 1's
    [1] Binary - Each byte in data file contains 8 bits of data

   Select input mode:  1
```

I want to know if I'm doing everything right. And what will be the changes if I set the input parameter to 10,000 and the number of bitstreams to 1000?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: In hindsight you're probably talking about an encryption algorithm? You haven't specified anything other than "encrypted file" when it comes to the algorithm so I initially tagged it for a PRNG, but that's probably wrong. Please add details & retag.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I have an encryption algorithm. By using algorithm i try to encrypt file with a lot of texts. After the work of my algorithm, I get a file with ciphertext at the output. Since i want to test my algorithm for nist statistical tests i provide encrypted file

Comment: Yes, you're doing it right :-) and welcome wxist.  So, if you're uncertain of the input, what about the output? Post it please...

Comment: 1000 bitstreams will not tell you anything.

Comment: @PaulUszak i got another question about output of NIST statistical tests, it would be great if you check it out

Comment: I closed the question because the OP posted another a [more detailed version](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/105535/555)